# Concept Of Permutation To Solve A Problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a problem with the concept of permutation . The problem description is as follows :

> Md Asad has 5 children and 8 nephews . All of them are to be seated in a row . Nephews like the last 4 seats of the row . Md Asad does not want to make arrangement for sitting of nephews beside him .
>
> Now I want to know ,what is the number of ways of seating Md Asad ? what is the number of way of seating of Md Asad's nephews? what is the number of way of seating Md Asads children ?

I have tried to solve the above problem but could not get the logics. Can you please help me to properly formulate the problem? How can I solve the problem above?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying the only condition is that the nephews must be sitting in the last 4 positions?

Comment: Nephews can not sit beside Md Asad . That is another condition .

Comment: Ok, so let me make sure I understand this. There are two conditions: 1. the last 4 positions must be filled by nephews, and 2. nephews cannot sit next to Asad?

Comment: Yes, You have understood the problem .

Comment: I think I understand the problem (see my answer below), but I don't understand the "wrong concept" part in the title. Which concept is wrong here?

Comment: Marc , sorry for the title . The title has been changed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make two preliminary observations: (1) any solution will give rise to a packet of $5!8!$ solutions with the same attribution of each of the $14$ seats to one of Asad/child/nephew, namely by permuting the children and nephews among each other; therefore one can count the valid such attributions and multiply by $5!8!$. (2) Md Asad must sit in position $1\leq i\leq 9$, since he cannot be next to one of the nephews in positions $11,12,13,14$.

Positions $11,\ldots,14$ must be attributed to nephews and can henceforth be ignored (there are $4$ positions for nephews left). Now two somewhat different cases occur depending on whether Md Asad is in position$~1$ or not. If he is in position$~1$, then position$~2$ must be a child, and the remaining $8$ positions can be attributed to $4$ children and $4$ remaining nephews in any of the $\binom84$ possible ways. If on the other hand Md Asad is position $2\leq i\leq 9$, then both positions next to him are to be attributed to children, and it remains to attribute the remaining $7$ positions to $3$ children and $4$ nephews in $\binom73$ possible ways. Since there are $8$ similar such cases the final result is
$$
  \left(\binom84+8\binom73\right)\times5!\times8!
 =350\times120\times40320 = 1\,693\,440\,000.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the last $4$ spaces can only be filled by nephews, there are $\binom{8}{4}4!$ different ways that they can be seated.

As for the second condition, Asad must have $2$ children sitting next to him (unless he sits at the edge, which will be considered separately). To that end, there are $8$ different places for Asad and the $2$ children to sit. Within that seating there are $2$ possible arrangements of the children (on either side of Asad). The rest of the $7$ seats can have $7!$ possible arrangements.

$$8\cdot2\cdot7!$$

In the case that Asad sits at the edge, one of his children must be sitting beside him. The rest of the $8$ seats can have $8!$ arrangements:

$$8!$$

Now use the rule of product and rule of sums to get the total:

$$(8!+8\cdot2\cdot7!)\cdot\binom{8}{4}4!$$

Incidentally, this happens to equal the simpler equation:

$$3\cdot8!\cdot\binom{8}{4}4!$$

Comment: That means , according to you , Md Asad can sit in 3.8!.4! way ?

Comment: What is the solution of other question ?

Comment: I can not understood your logic about overall seating arrangement .

Comment: @OchenaPothik Can you be more specific about what you can't understand?

Comment: This answer is obviously wrong, as it should be divisible by the $5!8!$ permutations of the children and nephews among each other.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're right, I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: My above comment is only for Andre Nicolas .

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is divisible by that. There's the $5$ in the $\binom{8}{4}$, along with the $4!$ which makes $5!$.

Comment: @OchenaPothik: If we are only interested in where Md Asad sits, there are $9$ possibilities.

Comment: What is the number of overall seating arrangement ?

Comment: @Ataraxia: The answer was changed (I think) after I wrote the comment above. While it is now divisible by $5!8!$, it is still wrong: I compute $3\cdot8!\cdot\binom844!=203\,212\,800$ which is a lot less than the $1\,693\,440\,000$ I found. An error already occurs in the very first sentence: focussing on the nephews only there are $\binom84\times8!$ ways to seat just them (but this is a bad way to start anyway, as the number of possibilities for Md Asad depends on the seating of the nephews, and may even be impossible e.g. when the nephews are in places $2,5,7,9,11,12,13,14$).